# IronPython invocation from C# (with SciPy) fails with ImportException: "No module named mtrand"

Tags: c#, numpy, scipy, ironpython, python.net

I have a python library I am trying to use via IronPython (v2.7 RC1 [2.7.0.30]) invocation from C# application. The library uses NumPy and SciPy quite extensively, which **does work** with [SciPy and NumPy for .NET](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net) when ran using ipy from command line like this:

```
ipy.exe -X:Frames file_from_lib_importing_numpy.py
```

However, when I invoke IronPython from C# using the code below, an exception is thrown:

```
ImportException
"No module named mtrand"
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(Object value)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportStar(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   ...
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime.ExecuteFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime.UseFile(String path)
   ...
```

The C# code (a part of it) that invokes IronPython is as follows:

```
    ScriptEngine _engine;

    var opts = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    opts["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;
    _engine = Python.CreateEngine(opts);

    var sp = _engine.GetSearchPaths();
    sp.Add(@"c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7");
    sp.Add(@"c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\DLLs");
    sp.Add(@"c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
    sp.Add(@"c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages");
    sp.Add(_path);
    _engine.SetSearchPaths(sp);

    var _runtime = _engine.Runtime;
    var scope = _runtime.ExecuteFile(Path.Combine(_path, "mytest.py"));
```

For testing purposes I am executing the following file 'mytest.py':

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7')
    sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\DLLs')
    sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
    sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages')

    import os, os.path
    cd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    if not cd in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    import numpy as np
    print 'OK'

    x = np.array([1,2])
    print x
```

Which fails on the line 12 'import numpy as np'. 
The problem is that the file `__init__.py` in IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random\ contains the following line

```
from mtrand import *
```

which fails. Note that the mtrand is not a module, it is a *directory*.
I can not think of anything else I can try to make this work, so I would very much appreciate any help from you.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the output of `print sys.path`, *AND* does `sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7')` after `import sys` give the same results?

Comment: You are right, when invoking from C#, the `sys.path` does not contain the paths set up in the application. Furthermore, when I add the line `sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7')` it fails with "No module named **numpy**". Do I really need to set up the paths in each python file that I want to use from C# app?

Comment: In other words, what is the purpose of setting up the search paths when they don't propagate into the python runtime?

Comment: Adding the paths to the python file did not solve the problem - still same exception thrown. The sys.path seems to be set up correctly (contains the appended paths, the Lib and Dll dirs of C# application CWD, and the directory of the file under execution), and numpy at least starts to get imported.

Answer (score 12):

Not the best soultion, but its works for me:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7')
sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs')
sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
sys.path.append(r'c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages')

import clr
clr.AddReference('mtrand.dll')

import numpy
import scipy

print numpy.__version__
print scipy.__version__
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: hmm, and how exactly did you build mtrand.dll? I tried pyc.py script, i.e. running `ipy pyc.py /main:..\..\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand\generate_mtrand_c.py /out:mtrand /target:dll` but that wasn't sucessful either

Comment: I didn't build it. The installer copy it into the `c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs` folder.

Comment: Nice. This worked for me after lots of headaches... If it helps someone I'm calling it within C# like this...  var lang = Python.CreateLanguageSetup(null);
                lang.Options["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;
                var setup = new ScriptRuntimeSetup();
                setup.LanguageSetups.Add(lang);
                var runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
                var engine = runtime.GetEngine("py");

                engine.ExecuteFile("mytest.py");

Comment: Worked for me too - however I have no idea why this should be necessary. After all all the DLLs are in the same directory, and the others seem to load without doing AddReference on them.

Answer (score 1):

I found that, in my ActivePython V2.7.0.2, this works:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Examples')
import examples
```

(assuming examples.py is in C:\Examples). This doesn't (without the r):

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Examples')
import examples
```

Because I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named examples
```

Conclusion: mind the r''!

Comment: In a string literal prefixed with "**r**" the escape sequences starting with \ are disabled. This is convenient for filepaths since \ is the path separator and you don't want it to start an escape sequence.

(r'C:\Examples') == ('C:\\Examples')