# IronPython unable to run script that imports numpy

Tags: .net, python-2.7, numpy, ironpython, python.net

Disclaimer - I'm not familiar with Python. I'm a C# developer who has written an application to execute Python scripts (authored by others) using IronPython. These scripts have so far have only needed to use `import math`, but one of our users has asked for the application to support for Numpy.

I have installed Numpy on my PC (using the 'numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe' file), which has created a numpy folder under \Lib\site-packages. I've written a two-line Python script to test that Numpy is accessible:-

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2])
```

I run the script from within C#:-

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.SetSearchPaths(new Collection<string>(new[]
{
    @"C:\Python27", 
    @"C:\Python27\DLLs", 
    @"C:\Python27\Lib", 
    @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages", 
    @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy",
    @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core"
}));
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
var scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
    _myPythonScript, 
    SourceCodeKind.Statements);
scriptSource.Execute(scope);
```

Despite setting all those search paths, the last line throws an `ImportException`:-

> cannot import multiarray from numpy.core

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526151/ironpython-invocation-from-c-sharp-with-scipy-fails-with-importexception-no) SO article is similar, but didn't help - the first answer mentions an 'mtrand.dll' file, which I don't seem to have.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the main limitation of IronPython - it does not support C-API of CPython. Hence you need to use pythonnet:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

You can try pure python implementation of numpy:

https://github.com/wadetb/tinynumpy

Answer (score 2):

"multiarray" is a .pyd file, and unless someone can correct me, it appears that these aren't supported by IronPython ([How can I import a .PYD module in IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228613/how-can-i-import-a-pyd-module-in-ironpython)).