# Any workable way to use Python scripts with scipy and numpy libraries and Unity?

Tags: python, c#, numpy, unity-game-engine, scipy

I want to use Unity to create some kind of GUI for some my data analysis scripts made with Python language.
I tried to use IronPython by using this guide [Use Python with Unity3D Guide](https://mikalikes.men/use-python-with-unity-3d-the-definitive-guide/), but had a problem with numpy library. I found a non-ideal solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299837/ironpython-unable-to-run-script-that-imports-numpy) - it's about tinynumpy.
However the using of scipy isn't possible by this way.
Is the any solution to use Python libraries and Unity with no limits?

Comment: You should tell more precisely what Your "problem with numpy library" is.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use python with unity? It doesnt make sense for me but it might just be me. I would actually reonmend you using another game engine if you are going to be using pyrhon, such as the godot game egine. It's main laguage is the same as python.